# Can you filter a single item from a CollectionViewSource

Tags: wpf, collectionviewsource

I want to filter out a single item in my CollectionViewSource

I already have other filters applied, but I'm trying to find a way of filtering out an individual item without having to call a function that iterates through all items.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why not just adjust your existing filter? It already runs for every item in the collection...

Comment: Because that's the point. I don't want to run against every item in the source list. I want to avoid iterating over each and every item again and again and again - Ideally I would like to specify an item and flag it as filtered.

Comment: If at first place you know you want to filter out that item from collection irrespective of any condition then why you add it to the base list??

Comment: No, at first I want it included, but later under strict conditions I want to filter an item out temporarily. The item(s) can't be filtered using the existing filter handlers because the condition is temporary and the main filter methods will change the status back to 'normal' if the other filters are reapplied.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear what you're asking, or what your concern is. Perhaps if you elaborate I could give a better answer.

However, as I see it, you have these options:

- Don't include the item in the underlying collection (or have a separate collection that does not contain it) and base your collection view on that
- Adjust your existing filter so that it excludes the object in question
- Create another collection view over your existing collection view that filters out the item

If the item is in the underlying collection, how else could you reasonably exclude it but via the filter?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by creating another CollectionView over hte the existing CollectionView?